# Borrow jQuery's show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.foo').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var fooText = $this.text();
    var displayFunction = (fooText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) != -1) ? $.show : $.hide;
    displayFunction.apply($this);
    displayFunction.apply($this.next());
}
```

Looks like $.show and $.hide are undefined, how can I resolve this?

Comment: `$this.toggle(true/false)` would be a better approach in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$.fn.show` and `$.fn.hide`.

All instances of `$` inherit the methods defined on `$.fn`, which is an alias for the prototype of jQuery. Alternatively you could use `$().hide` but there's no need to create an instance.